# Text Editor Won't Close and Crashes in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a model in R using PVA and transition matrices.  Whenever I run a line and the text editor spreadsheet pops up, I am able to edit the data but it won't close and just freezes so I have to shut everything down. I've tried restarting several times but I can't get it to work and I need to be able to run this line of code.  Specifically it happens when I run "supplement_matrix <- make.supplement.matrix(num.stages)"  Here is my code:

```
library(popbio)
library(reshape2)
library(expm)
multiyear.stages <- read.csv('multiyear_stages_longform.csv')
head(multiyear.stages)
unique(multiyear.stages$Survey)
nrow(multiyear.stages[multiyear.stages$Survey==1,])

nrow(multiyear.stages[multiyear.stages$Survey==1&multiyear.stages$Stage==1,])

nrow(multiyear.stages[multiyear.stages$Survey==2,])
nrow(multiyear.stages[multiyear.stages$Survey==2&multiyear.stages$Stage==2,])
nrow(multiyear.stages[multiyear.stages$Survey==1&multiyear.stages$Stage<=2,])

nrow(multiyear.stages[multiyear.stages$Survey<=2&multiyear.stages$Stage==1,])

nrow(multiyear.stages[multiyear.stages$Survey==2&multiyear.stages$Stage==2,])

plants<-dcast(multiyear.stages, ID~Survey, value.var="Stage", fill=-1,             
fun.aggregate=mean)
head(plants)

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==1&plants$"2"==2,]) 

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==1&plants$"2"==0,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==1&plants$"2"==1,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==1&plants$"2"==3,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==2&plants$"2"==0,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==2&plants$"2"==1,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==2&plants$"2"==2,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==2&plants$"2"==3,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==3&plants$"2"==1,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==3&plants$"2"==2,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==3&plants$"2"==3,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==-1&plants$"3"==1,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==1&plants$"3"==0,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==1&plants$"3"==1,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==1&plants$"3"==2,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==1&plants$"3"==3,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==2&plants$"3"==0,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==2&plants$"3"==1,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==2&plants$"3"==2,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==3&plants$"3"==3,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==3&plants$"3"==0,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==3&plants$"3"==1,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==3&plants$"3"==2,])

nrow(plants[plants$"2"==3&plants$"3"==3,])

nrow(plants[plants$"1"==3,])

A<-cbind(c(0.317,0.384,0.017), c(0.071,0.592,0.195), c(0.02,0.76,0.1))

N0<-c(40,136,38)
N0 %*% A

source('PVA_source.R')

num.stages<-3

num.iter<-50

num.years<-50

num.iter<-10

num.years<-10

quasi_extinction_threshold<-10

carrying_capacity<-1000

number_of_plants_in_year_1_Stage1 <-cbind(c(19), c(12), c(1))

transition_matrix<-cbind(c(0.317,0.384,0.017), c(0.071,0.592,0.195),    
c(0.02,0.76,0.1))

fertility <- c(2.475)

supplement_matrix <- make.supplement.matrix(num.stages)
```

Here are links to the data I'm using

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwRwgnqxDOlxUWNyS25FYVpOZFk/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwRwgnqxDOlxZXUzX2EwM2NOZEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It runs fine for me in RStudio. I don't know what the problem is, but is there a need to use that pop up tool to create your matrix? Can't you just write the code to create it?

Comment: I just tried it in RStudio and it worked.  Not sure why it matters but thanks!

Comment: Glad that it worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose the problem, because I can't replicate it (it runs fine for me). However, you can work around it.

Here's the function from that PVA script that's freezing your system:

```
make.supplement.matrix<-function(num.stages){
    supplement <- matrix(0,nrow=num.stages,,ncol=1,
            dimnames=list(paste('stage',1:num.stages),'Number of extra plants to plant each year')
        )
    supplement <- edit(supplement)
    supplement
}
```

Instead of using it, why not just run:

```
supplement <- matrix(0,nrow=num.stages,,ncol=1,
        dimnames=list(paste('stage',1:num.stages),'Number of extra plants to plant each year')
    )
```

then manually edit (in your script or interactive console) the matrix called supplement any way you please?